# fixed img on a profile

Tags: html

help i like to put this code on my profile this tag in html with css layout works but not on some ones host web site

```
<a href=" page here" style="display:scroll; position:fixed; bottom:5px; right:5px;" target=" _blank " title=""><img src=" img here " border="0"/></a>
```

Comment: What doesn't work? What happens?

Comment: What profile?  Define "some ones host web site."  In what way does it not work?

Comment: FYI: `scroll` isn't a valid value for the `display` property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no such property as `display: scroll`, try `display: block`.

Comment: <a style="display:scroll;position:fixed;bottom:225px;right:5px;" href="#GoDown"><img style="border:0;" src="http://i32.tinypic.com/16lle91.png"/></a>

Comment: It looks like you've missed `http://` from the `src` attribute. This could explain why it doesn't work somewhere else.

Comment: <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="down" scrollamount="10" style="position:absolute; left:148px; top:190px; width:90px; height:2274px; z-index:1;"><span class="falling2"><img src="http://www.crazykens.com/Pages/falling-objects/spider_hanging.gif" /></span></marquee>